How to remove space from svg file in PHP
How to remove the white space in svg file?
This is the my svg file.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin:auto;display:block;" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"/>

    <circle cx="72" cy="50" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-0.9s"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.9s"></animate>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="67.79837387624885" cy="62.93127555043441" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-0.8s"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.8s"></animate>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="56.798373876248846" cy="70.92324335849338" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-0.7s"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.7s"></animate>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="43.20162612375116" cy="70.92324335849338" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-0.6s"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.6s"></animate>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="32.201626123751154" cy="62.931275550434414" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-0.5s"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.5s"></animate>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="28" cy="50" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-0.4s"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.4s"></animate>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="32.201626123751154" cy="37.06872444956559" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-0.3s"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.3s"></animate>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="43.201626123751154" cy="29.076756641506623" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-0.2s"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.2s"></animate>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="56.79837387624884" cy="29.07675664150662" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-0.1s"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.1s"></animate>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="67.79837387624885" cy="37.068724449565586" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0s"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="0s"></animate>
    </circle>
</svg>



I have used imagemagick, but it doesn't work well.

Use viewBox="24 24 52 52" instead of viewBox="0 0 100 100" for the svg element. In order to know the value for the viewBox you can use the getBBox() JS method.

What has this question to do with PHP? I think you should remove it from the title.

Looks like you calculate <circle> positions with PHP Server Side
You can save server CPU Cycles with Christian his answer using rotate,
and a Web Component in the <head> of your document
to generate the SVG Client Side (and no spaces in the HTML)
and animate with SMIL
(I dismissed the subtle animated color change for brevity)


<svg-spinner></svg-spinner>
<svg-spinner dots=18></svg-spinner>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-spinner", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = 
        `<svg height=100 viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" style=background:beige>` +
          Array( ~~(this.getAttribute("dots")  || 10) )
            .fill(  this.getAttribute("color") || "#007a5c" )
            .map((v, i, a) =>
              `<circle transform=rotate(${i*(360/a.length)}) fill=${v} cx=10>` +
              `  <animate attributeName=r begin=${i*1/a.length} values=1;2 
                          dur=1s repeatCount=indefinite />` +
              `</circle>`)
            .join("") + 
        `</svg>`
    }
  })
</script>

<svg-spinner color=blue></svg-spinner>



And for those saying But this requires JavaScript...
If you need a spinner on a webpage I bet you, my wife's car, your user  is waiting for a sh*load of JavaScript to download.

Not that is makes that much of a difference, but instead of placing each circle element "absolute" you can place the circles in a grouping element (<g>) and use transform/rotate to place the circles.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" viewBox="0 0 52 52" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
  <g transform="translate(26 26)">
    <circle transform="rotate(0)" cx="22" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-.9s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-.9s" />
    </circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(36)" cx="22" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-.8s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-.8s" />
    </circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(72)" cx="22" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-.7s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-.7s" />
    </circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(108)" cx="22" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-.6s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-.6s" />
    </circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(144)" cx="22" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-.5s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-.5s" />
    </circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(180)" cx="22" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-.4s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-.4s" />
    </circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(216)" cx="22" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-.3s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-.3s" />
    </circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(252)" cx="22" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-.2s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-.2s" />
    </circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(288)" cx="22" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="-.1s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="-.1s" />
    </circle>
    <circle transform="rotate(324)" cx="22" fill="#007a5c" r="4">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="2.4;2.4;4;2.4;2.4" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" values="#007a5c;#007a5c;#125443;#007a5c;#007a5c" repeatCount="indefinite" times="0;0.1;0.2;0.3;1" dur="1s" begin="0s" />
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>




Or no <g> at all and a viewBox="-26 -26 54 54"

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman but look at the cx and cy attributes of the circles. I my book my solution is much clearer .

Yes, clearer is subjective, (gzipped) file size is not

Just re-read your comment. I meant setting the viewBox on your version; both are translations (your translate on the  or the translate in the viewBox)

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman ok, I missed that. You are right. I would still prefer the <g> for the readability.
